# disks are SSD, but /sys/block/vdb/queue/rotational says it's rotational - should i worry?

Tags: hard-disk, kvm, ssd

Is it a problem when the system believes a device to be rotational, but it is SSD really? The system is:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- KVM virtualized
- I have /dev/vda as "local", /dev/vdb as "isilon"; I'm interested primarily in vda (see background below)
- The provider says "[/dev/vda is] a SSD raid 6 array within the HV"
- `cat /sys/block/vd?/queue/rotational
  1
  1`
- `lsblk -d -o name,rota
  NAME ROTA
  sr0     1
  vda     1
  vdb     1`
- it's fast (dd random test according to https://serverfault.com/questions/551453/how-do-i-verify-that-my-hosting-provider-gave-me-ssds/551495#551495; takes 1.379s; However, it's emtpy still)
- driver: virtio_blk

Is this configured correctly? Should I worry once there's data, and Elasticsearch running on /dev/vda (or /dev/vdb)?

Background: I'm installing elsasticsearch and was checking if the SSD scheduler is correct, but as the system doesn't see the disks as SSD, it comes back with

`cat /sys/block/vda/queue/scheduler
[none]`

Comment: Depending on the services that require to use that disk there can be some impact. I'm familiar with this in ceph context on HP servers, where the OSD metadata depends on the correct configuration. We use a custom udev rule with a small script that sets the rotational flag correctly. If you encounter any issues in the present configuration I would suggest to do so, too.

Comment: Use virtio-scsi, not virtio-blk.

Answer (score 1):

vda implies it's a virtual drive, so linux doesn't know the physical details and robably reports the defaults

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `virtio_blk` device cannot even properly hint if the device is rotational or not. At least it was true in 2022, see https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1498042#c27

To sum up:

1. virtualization developers didn't think it was a worthy feature to implement
2. `/sys/block/vda/queue/scheduler` is writable, so if you care, you can write `0` there